# Firefox/chrome shows apache request as blocked / stalled

Tags: apache, get

I'm using Apache 2.4.33 running on MacOs 10.13.6 as a local web development server

I ran some updates last week, mainly to update php from 7.1 to 7.2.  This included a few tweaks to my httpd.conf namely to load a different php module.

I also recreated the server self-signed certificates as per instructions here: https://gist.github.com/jonathantneal/774e4b0b3d4d739cbc53

I've started getting errors on some web pages where some files included in the page are blank.  these are both .js and .css files.

If I refresh the page, it is always the same 2 or 3 files.

As this is a dev environment, the files are sym linked from the web/assets directory through to the source directories.

I can't see any permissions problems.  Other files in the same directory, with same ownership and permissions don't have the same error.

Looking at the network panel in FF, it lists the file, no error status, not even 200 - completely blank.  I can't see the file in the Apache access_log either. Nothing in the error log.
[image: FF network tab]

If I look at the "Timings" sub-tab, it has a status of blocked.
[image: FF timings tab]

I'm not running the MacOs firewall.

My htaccess is very basic:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*

# We need mod_rewrite for enablePrettyUrl
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# If the directory or file exists, use the request directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Otherwise forward the request to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

It's not CORS/cross domain ...

In FF the console gives a "Loading failed" error
in Chrome it gives "net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"

So, blocked by what?

Answer (score 1):

it seems as though I had 2 versions of PHP installed.  Apache line though I was using a homebrew installed version of 7.0 and the command line thought I was using the native 7.1

I guess somehow these were conflicting.

I ran brew uninstall php@7.0, brew cleanup & brew prune.  Rebooted and everything worked OK.